# Search button google map is not working on my vf page

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

i am newbie  .I am integrating Google map and there is a field city along with search button. Google map is showing but search button is not working

Any help would be appreciate :)

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/jsv=3.exp&signed_in=true&libraries=places"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var map;
 function initializeField() {
 var input = document.getElementById('page:frm:field');           
 var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input); 
 var mapOptions = {
 zoom:6,
 mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
 mapTypeControl: false,


 center: new google.maps.LatLng(20.593684,78.962880)
 };
 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('MyMap'),mapOptions);
 new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    map: map
  });

}
<button class="btn customBtn pull-right"value="Search"onclick="map_selected = true; initialize(); return false;"></button>
```

Comment: What do you expect the search button to do?  It just re-runs the initialize routine.

Comment: user can enter the city  whatever and after this i want to store the  geolocation and radius in the backend.

Comment: You need to implement that functionality.

Comment: @geocodezip yes will do but the  action is not  working on my button ?  or  if the search button will not work as  aanadh sp  said   then is there any other way to do this  can you please  help me out ?

Comment: What action?  In your posted code the button executes the initialize function, I can't try, as you haven't posts a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but I would expect that is working correctly as coded (assuming you have an initialize function somewhere on your page).

Answer (score 0):

Search button will not work

In google map will works have to give latitude and longitude

In your Codings the latitude and longitude has been already setted as
lat 20.593684
Lon 78.962880

So location can be shown Khattalwada, Wadgaon, Maharashtra 442305, India

Comment: yes.. But if the person   belong from other city then . like he need to fill the street address along with city and whatever city, it will be shown on Google map.. How it  is possible?

Comment: I think its not possible. Surf in google you will get better ideas